# How to use `endswith()` against multiple values in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have a `string` and I want to use `endswith()` on it but against multiple values.

My first guess was to try it with a tuple:

```
# {string}

suffixes = ({multiple suffixes here})

endswith(i,extensions)
```

This generated the error message:

`MethodError: no method matching endswith(::String, ::Tuple{String, String})`

So, I went looking for official documentation at [Julia documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/) but they only talk about single string comparions.

I did find this on an [unofficial site](http://www.jlhub.com/julia/manual/en/function/endswith) that says:

> If the second argument is a vector or set of characters, tests whether the last character of `string` belongs to that set.

Which does not quite apply.

I tried the following variations:

`endswith(i,extensions[:])`

Produces the same error as before
`MethodError: no method matching endswith(::String, ::Tuple{String, String})`

Variations with list:

```
# {string}

suffixes = [{multiple suffixes here}]

endswith(i,extensions)
```

Only changes the error message from tuple to vector

`MethodError: no method matching endswith(::String, ::Vector{String})`

Or with the index supplied

```
# {string}

suffixes = [{multiple suffixes here}]

endswith(i,extensions[:])
```

Same error

`MethodError: no method matching endswith(::String, ::Vector{String})`

I tried `endswith(i,extensions[1:length(extensions)])` with both tuples and vectors and that did not work either.

Anyone familiar?

Comment: It is not entirely clear whether you want a list of result (true/false for each suffix), or determine whether _any_ of the suffixed match.

Comment: Did I want a boolean array or the subset of the list that satisfied the criteria? The latter is what I wanted. So, for a `string` that can have any suffix, I wanted to test the `string` against a list of `suffixes` of my choice. For example, test `file.pep` against `[".pep",".txt",".xlsx']` and since `.pep` is in the list the string `file.pep` passes the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want the following:

```
julia> endswith.("abcd", ["d", "c", "cd", "dc"])
4-element BitVector:
 1
 0
 1
 0
```

Note the `.` after `endswith`. This operation broadcasts the function over the collection (in this case vector of suffixes). For more information see [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-vectorized).

Comment: Yep, this was it.  This fails inside a for loop, do know where I can look into the documentation for that? The error when using this inside a for loop was `non-boolean (BitVector) used in boolean context`

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "this fails inside a for loop". Could you share the code?

Comment: Sorry, had to make a paste here https://www.pastery.net/cbqthg/.

Comment: in your code change to `push!(my_list,i)`

Comment: That WAS a syntax error but that is not is throwing the error `TypeError: non-boolean (BitVector) used in boolean context`. I changed the code to this https://www.pastery.net/qkkbsx/ and still get the same error. I am going to use `endswith(i,r".item_one|item_two|...")` inside the for loop since that is not causing boolean issues. Apologies, I started using Julia this morning and am trying to tackle the learning curve of coming from python.

Comment: OK - then the other problem is `endswith.(i,[".fna",".pep"])` returns you a vector of bool, so you need `any(endswith.(i,[".fna",".pep"]))` or `any(v -> endswith(i, v), [".fna",".pep"])`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246704/discussion-between-rijan-dhakal-and-bogumil-kaminski).

Answer (score 4):

It seems the following is also possible:

```
endswith("{string}",r"item_one|item-two|item_three|item_four") # items being what I want to check the string for.
```

And if my items are dynamic I guess I can use an f-string to create the r"{item_list_here}"

Comment: The dynamic construction would be `Regex(join(suffixes, "|"))`.